# Trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape yelp ratings and export to csv, the csv though ONLY has the review comments and not rating or ID

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape 100 reviews/ratings on a Yelp restaurant for an assignment using BeautifulSoup. I'm specifically looking for:
Review Comment
Review ID
Review Rating

I'm pretty new to Python and I feel like I've missed something extremely obvious

Here's what I've got so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
```

`url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/ichiran-times-square-new-york-4?osq=Ichiban+Ramen' ourUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl,'html.parser') type(soup) print(soup.prettify())`

`for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class':" arrange-unit__373c0__3XPkE arrange-unit-fill__373c0__38Zde border-color--default__373c0__r305k"}): ID.append(i.find("div").get("aria-label"))`

`soup.find('p', {'class':"comment__373c0__Nsutg css-n6i4z7"})`

`i = soup.find('p', {'class':"comment__373c0__Nsutg css-n6i4z7"}) i.text`

```
review=[]
rating = []
ID = []

for x in range(0,10):

url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/ichiran-times-square-new-york-4?osq=Ichiban+Ramen="+str(10*x)

ourUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl,'html.parser')

#for i in soup,


for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class':" i-stars__373c0___sZu0 i-stars--regular-5__373c0__20dKs border-color--default__373c0__1yxBb overflow--hidden__373c0__1TJqF"}):
    per_rating = i.text
    rating.append(per_rating)

for i in soup.find_all('span', {'class':" arrange-unit__373c0__3XPkE arrange-unit-fill__373c0__38Zde border-color--default__373c0__r305k"}):
    ID.append(i.find("div").get("aria-label"))

for i in soup.find_all('p', {'class':"comment__373c0__Nsutg css-n6i4z7"}):
    per_review=i.text 
    review.append(per_review)
```

`len(review)`

Here's my attempt at exporting to csv where I get review text ONLY and nothing else:

```
with open('Review.csv','a',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     for each in review:
          f.write(each+'\n')
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables (especially what you have in HTML) because servers may send different HTML for different browsers or devices.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - Updated**

The issue actually looks due to not targeting the correct tags in the HTML.

```
# Import regex package
import re

# Narrow down the section that you are searching in to avoid erroneous elements
child = soup.find('div', {'class': 'css-79elbk border-color--default__373c0__1ei3H'})

for x in child.find_all('span', {'class':"fs-block css-m6anxm"}):
    # Ignore the titular "Username"
    if x.text != 'Username':
        ID.append(x.text)

for x in child.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile(r'i-stars.+')}):
    rating.append(x.get('aria-label'))

for x in child.find_all('p', {'class':'comment__373c0__Nsutg css-n6i4z7'}):
    comment = x.find('span', {'class':'raw__373c0__tQAx6'})
    review.append(comment.text)
```

The `ID` needed to target the specific element, `'class':"fs-block css-m6anxm"`, and the `rating` class differed depending on how many stars it achieved so implementing regex to identify anything beginning with `i-stars`.

**Original Answer**

I believe your issue is that you are only looping through `review` when you also need to loop `ID` and `rating` also: -

```
# Create new_line to work around f-strings issue with '\'
new_line = '\n'

with open('Review.csv','a',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     for i in range(len(review):
          f.write(f'{review[i]},{ID[i]},{rating[i]}{new_line}')
```

You could also take a look at the [Pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) in order to achieve this.

You can create a dataframe and then export that as a number of different file types, including CSV, for example: -

```
# Import Pandas package
import Pandas

# Store list values, along with column headings, in a dictionary
d = {'review_comment': review, 'review_id': ID, 'review_rating': rating}

# Create dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Export the dataframe as a CSV
df.to_csv('desired/save/location.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: When trying to use pandas to export instead, I get an error:

Arrays must all be the same length

Also when trying to loop ID and rating, it looks like I also get a "list index out of range" error

Comment: I assume your other lists must be empty.  It looks like you are targeting the wrong tags. I am updating my answer to include these amendments.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but I still have a syntax error when attempting to export to csv using the loop methods and the "list of index out of range" error with trying to use pandas

Comment: There are other elements on the page that share the ones that you are searching for so I have updated my edit to attend to this.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working after my most recent change?

Answer (score 0):

Due to your code being not formatted properly, I wasn't able to debug the issue, but rewrote the code to fetch the required details.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import sleep

# Set the URL of the Yelp page for the restaurant
restaurant_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/ichiran-times-square-new-york-4'

# Set the headers for the HTTP request
headers = {
    'host': 'www.yelp.com'
}

# Use BeautifulSoup to parse the restaurant page HTML
restaurant_page = bs(requests.get(restaurant_url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')

# Extract the unique Yelp business ID for the restaurant
biz_id = restaurant_page.find('meta', {'name': 'yelp-biz-id'}).get('content')

# Extract the total number of reviews for the restaurant
review_count = int(restaurant_page.find('a', {'href': '#reviews'}).text.split(' ')[0])

# Create an dataframe to store the review data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[
        'Review Text',
        'Rating',
        'Date',
        'User ID' ,
        'User Profile URL',
        'User Review Count',
    ]
)

# Iterate through each review page (10 reviews per page)
for review_page in range(0, review_count, 10):
    # Construct the API URL to fetch reviews for the given page
    review_api_url = f'https://www.yelp.com/biz/{biz_id}/review_feed?rl=en&q=&sort_by=relevance_desc&start={review_page}'

    # Send a request to the review API and get the JSON response
    review_data = requests.get(review_api_url, headers=headers).json()

    # Iterate through each review in the response
    for review in review_data['reviews']:
        # Append the extracted data as a dictionary to the 'data' list
        df.loc[len(df)] = {
            'Review Text': review['comment']['text'],
            'Rating': review['rating'],
            'Date': review['localizedDate'],
            'User ID': review['userId'],
            'User Profile URL': 'https://www.yelp.com' + review['user']['link'],
            'User Review Count': review['user']['reviewCount'],
        }

        # Print the last added review data
        print(df.loc[len(df)-1])
        df.to_csv('Yelp Reviews.csv', index=None)
        sleep(10)
```

I have used `sleep(10)` to wait for 10 seconds upon extracting each review, as Yelp is quick to block IPs requesting in bulk and I got my IP blocked as well while testing.

Sample Output of CSV of this code is:
[image]